# Xamarin option disappeared from new projects

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have successfully installed xamarin, i created one application by it, after i installed visual c++, framework 4.5 and repaired the visual studio one time during the installation, Xamrin option disappeared from new projects. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Open the visual studio click on Help->About Microsoft Visual studio
check. Is there xamarin is available  or not, if not go to control panel and update the visual studio.

[image]

Comment: Yes. It is not available there, but i installed and worked on it, it took 1 day to download. However it should be downloaded again :(.

Comment: Make sure you have checked Xamarin studio and all related framework on installation time.you have updated the visual studio from control Panel and select the Xamarin studio etc.